# Loading a React webpage into an iframe on a asp.net webforms website with authentication

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, identityserver4

I have a complex requirement, where we have an asp.net webforms site we want to try and upgrade in a step by step way. We are considering using React (frontend, with asp.net core backend) for this purpose. The website has an iframe in the centre, and we want to try and replace the old content with the new completely separately hosted React content. This needs to occur after clicking a link on the asp.net webforms page.

I managed to create a ‘Create React app’ website prototype and it was simple to load it into the iframe by linking directly to the React website. I came unstuck when I wanted to try and add an authentication token into the header (oauth2 with openid connect for use with IdentityServer). The only way I could see to do this was to try using javascript to add the header by making an XMLHttpRequest object (or I tried also using the Fetch API) and this partially worked but not everything was correctly loaded.

I see for example an answer here [How to embed React App into another website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836102/how-to-embed-react-app-into-another-website) which I assume is the best way to add the website into an iframe.

So, I can’t find much on the internet about dealing with authentication… I guess because asp.net webforms are so old by now, but I assume others have wanted to do something similar before. The question I have, is what would be considered to be the best way to do this? I don’t know if I’m going in completely the wrong direction.

Comment: Part of your problem is the iframe. Iframes are separate contexts in terms of authentication. Why don't just put the app in a div instead? All your fetches would go to the server with your forms auth cookie.

Comment: ok thanks, I'd seen that others are using divs as in the link i posted. But that means, as I was suspecting, that I have to use cookie authentication instead of having the token in the header as I did with a blazor wasm mobile app I have created, right? And then the question is whether I need a completely separate cookie for oauth2 auth with identityserver. I assume that a forms auth cookie is not going to be compatable?

Comment: If the react app will sit in a div, it will make requests with the forms cookie. Which means that your server controllers will be authenticated like any other server resources ([Authorize] will do).

Comment: Ok thanks, I was hoping to go with the oauth2 token authentication really. But maybe I will have to stick with forms auth then. It will be a couple weeks before I can try and test that. It doesn't seem to be possible to upvote your comments... I'm not sure how to accept your answer if it works out.

Comment: Thanks, if you really want to credit my suggestion, I think you can come back when you finally have your approach settled. If your final approach follows my advice, let me know in a comment below, I will write down an answer based on the discussion we have here. If you, on the other hand, decide to make it on your own, just create an answer on your own so that others could benefit in future.

Comment: Hi, so it took me a long time to get back to this :( But I've decided to try with Blazor Wasm instead since we deal only with .net and React would be too much effort I think. But I'm still strugging with the authentication side of this... webforms just seems too old to integrate with anything. I was able to add the auth cookie as you suggested and I was wondering how the .net core application will know what to do with it... you can't simply add an authorize attribute... services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).

Comment: But, it seems to me that a webforms cookie is not compatable with a .net core cookie. You can share cookies across .net framework apps and .net core apps as specified [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana). So then I'm looking at how I might be able to use identityserver4 but I would want to be able to sign in manually via the webforms app and add the token to the blazor api calls on the front end. That looks equally difficult to pull off...